# Getting the position of a value inside a dataset that has three 1D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a dataset `precip_subset` that has three 1D numpy arrays. I merged 31 datasets to create `precip_subset`: the first numpy arrray in the dataset represents the day, the 2nd array represents the longitude, and the thrid array represents the latitude. There is a unique value for precipitation at each position in the dataset; for example, `print(precip_subset[1, 0, 21])` will give me a value of `1.05`.

In `precip_subset`, I only wanted specific values of precipitation. So I confined the dataset like so:

```
 data_low = precip_subset[(precip_subset > 0) & (precip_subset < 3.86667)]
```

Following this, I tried to do this:

```
for val in data_low:
    if val < 1:
        print(precip_subset.tolist().index(val))
```

What I am trying to do is get the position of the value in the original dataset, `precip_subset`. However, I get an error of `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Can anyone explain how I can get the position of a value from the `precip_subset`?

EDIT: Here is how precip_subset was created:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

data_path = r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\TRMM_3B42RT\3B42RT_Daily.201001.7.nc4"
f = Dataset(data_path)

latbounds = [ -31 , -19 ]
lonbounds = [ 131, 146 ] # degrees east ? 
lats = f.variables['lat'][:] 
lons = f.variables['lon'][:]

# latitude lower and upper index
latli = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[0] ) )
latui = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[1] ) ) 

# longitude lower and upper index
lonli = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[0] ) )
lonui = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[1] ) )

precip_subset = f.variables['precipitation'][ : , lonli:lonui , latli:latui ]
```

The variable "precipitation" is from the original dataset `r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\TRMM_3B42RT\3B42RT_Daily.201001.7.nc4"`

Also, the shape and size of precip_subset respectively is `(31, 60, 48)` and `89280`

Comment: It is not very clear how was `precip_subset` created... What it created by staking three 1D arrays? This should result in a 2D array which is contradicted by your usage example `precip_subset[1, 0, 21])` which shows that `precip_subset` is a 3D array. Therefore, please clarify the shape of your `precip_subset`array.

Comment: I'll post my whole code.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to create a small example of a numpy data array that represents your data. Your example does not show how data are arranged in your file and one needs to be familiar to `netCDF4` to answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following (assuming I got the idea correctly from your example):

```
data_low_indices1 = np.where((precip_subset > 0) & (precip_subset < 3.86667))
```

This will return a tuple of 1D arrays of indices for which condition holds. You may want to transpose this list:

```
data_low_indices2 = np.array(np.where((precip_subset > 0) & (precip_subset < 3.86667))).T
```

Then you can:

```
for ind in data_low_indices2:
    print(ind)
```

If you do not want to transpose, then do this:

```
for ind in zip(*data_low_indices1):
    print(ind)
```